# link to boost library

Tags: c++, build

I am trying to build a project using Boost's Asio , but I am getting linking error:

```
g++  -o homework main.o    -L/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/lib -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -L/home/student/boost_1_46_1/libs -lboost_system -lqt-mt -lXext -lX11 -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_system
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [homework] Error 1
```

How can I resolve the problem?

Comment: Is libboost_system in one of those link paths you specified?  If you perform a find on those directories looking for "libboost_system*" do you see the desired file?

Comment: Are you running a 64 bit system? If so, you'll need to include the 64 bit library path, probably something like "/home/student/boost_1_46_1/lib64"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's a typo. You said `-l boost_system` in command line, while it should be `-lboost_system`.

**Update:**
Nope! I get my answer back. Just found that it's OK to pass `-l <libname>`. In fact it's equal to `-l<libname>`. As others said, double-check paths.

Comment: I have changed the makefile as you suggested but still get the same error.

Comment: @VardanHovhannisyan Try checking paths. Which operating system you're using? Did you compiled boost yourself or installed precompiled package.

Comment: [soroush](http://stackoverflow.com/users/275221/soroush) thanks for reply. the lib path was wrong.